# Instances on points, selection of visible instances by alpha map values (1 / 0 );

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances, select

I got stuck at an important step and I need some help to understand what i'm doing wrong.
I'm looking for a way to tell blender to select instances (on faces) only for those on white color (solid, value=1) colored surface and ignore the background (transparency ,value=0). Object has also an UV map generated.
I attached the expected result also so you can make an idea what i want to create.
[image: My result]
[image: Expected result]
[image: UV map]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem here is that you did not connect any UV Map in the image vector socket

[image]

Comment: It works! Thank you!

Comment: @Mihael-IonuțFURDU Just a quick note: since you are using the _Alpha_ of the image, you need no _Separate Color_ node, because the _Image Texture_ node has an _Alpha_ output. The other thing is, the _Alpha_ value is black and white, so a _Selection_ input reads them as 0 and 1 or _False_ and _True_, so you don't need a _Compare_ node either. It works of course with all those nodes, but to make it easier to read the nodetree and for performance reasons it helps to get rid of nodes that are unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, I didn't thought of using the alpha directly, I just copied everything in the original screenshot tbh. But is the alpha always black or white in blender? I thought it could also read in between values